# How to Run Many Tor Browsers at once all with different IPs?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, geoip

Thank you for reading my question and taking an interested in helping me. I use the newest version of Tor on a Mac and the thing is when I download Tor, I do not end up with a "tor folder." I am interested as to how I can run multiple Tor browsers at once but each having a different IP. I did look through the other very informative threads, but as I said - I do not have a Tor Folder. Upon installation, all I end up with is the browser it self.

I was also interested as to how I can alter the IPs for them to be only from the United States. I followed all directions I found on threads by using torrc file and adding the needed text, but no luck at all! If you can also help me out with programing Tor to only show US IPs, I would highly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time and care. I wish nothing but harmony, luck and the best of all blessings.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might get a better answer if you explain;  Why you want to use multiple IP's simultaneously? or Why you want all the nodes related to your use of Tor to be in the US?

While you might know this already.
If you have the Tor Browser running, and want to change to a different IP, you would click on the green onion and specify new identity, although I am not sure if that resets all three nodes to potentially 3 other nodes.

I would feel that the NSA feels any use of Tor is potentially outside the US, and therefore the NSA can assume that they can surveil the connections involved.   The NSA should not be able to tell if all the nodes that you are using are in the US.  ?Curious also is that I have read that the NSA is not supposed to surveil US Citizens, however, does the NSA feel that they can surveil those who are in the US, but who are not citizens?   Can the NSA surveil US citizens in other countries?  (Supposing they know for sure that the person is a US citizen)  What is the Standard the NSA might use to determine whether a connection is use by a US Citizen, (only) that the NSA (NSA is not supposed to surveil (without a warrant) a US Citizen)  How does the NSA determine that they must desist from surveiling?  As we know that they pretty much do what they want, not sure it matters.  If anyone knows what standards they use, (which seems to be the goal of the OP) then pipe up and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

> I use the newest version of Tor on a Mac and the thing is when I download Tor, I do not end up with a "tor folder."

If you right-click on your Tor Browser (in your Applications folder) and then choose 'Show Package Contents' from the context menu, your `torrc` sits in `/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/`.

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple Tor Browsers at once, see [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/6904)

> This method launches multiple Tor instances, each with its own SocksPort and ControlPort. This ensures that the Tor Browsers are fully functional, portable, and self-contained. However, someone should confirm that I haven't missed anything that could compromise TBs security.
>
> 1. **Optional:** Download, verify, and install Tor Browser.
> 2. Make copies of the Tor Browser folder with different names (eg. Number them)
> 3. Launch Tor Browser
> 4. Edit about:config
>
>    - Modify extensions.torlauncher.control_port to a new ControlPort (eg. 9052 for Tor Browser 2)
> 5. Edit Torbutton Preferences
>
>    - Use custom proxy settings, and change the Port to SocksPort (eg. 9152 for Tor Browser 2)
> 6. Close Tor Browser
> 7. Edit torrc-defaults in \TorBrowser\Data\Tor
>
>    - Change SocksPort to what you set in step 5
>    - Change ControlPort to what you set in step 4
> 8. Launch Tor Browser, and check that everything was configured correctly
>
>    - Homepage (about:tor) should say "Congratulations!"
>    - Click "Test Tor Network Settings". check.torproject.org should say "Congratulations."
>    - Go to [ip-check.info](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/6904). Test should be all green and orange except Tab name. Authentication should be "protected". **Note:** It may not say that you are using Tor, but this is incorrect.
>    - **Optional:** Go to ipleak.net for IP, DNS, Geolocation, Browser and other info
>    - **Optional:** Test your browser fingerprint at [panopticlick.eff.org](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)
> 9. **Optional:** Edit about:config
>
>    - Type “banned" and modify the ports of the two entries. Add all the new SocksPort and ControlPort to the list (Copy the ports from other Tor Browsers)
> 10. **Optional:** Turn on “Forbid Scripts Globally” in NoScript for further security and privacy (also reduces browser fingerprint)
> 11. Repeat 3-10 for each Tor Browser folder
>
> Alternatively, this might be possible with a single Tor instance as the SocksPort and ControlPort. This would require the use of the control_auth_cookie (CookieAuthentication) or HashedControlPassword, and about:config extensions.torlauncher.start_tor=false. However, the browsers would not be self-contained and portable, as they would require a process that isn’t in their own directory.
>
> Inspired by mirimir's answer which seemed to compromise TB's security.