# Multiple Tor Browser instances without using VM/Sandboxies

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

On Windows is it possible to have multiple instances? I tried to copy paste Tor browser folder and running Tor Browser from it but did not worked.

Comment: Why would you want to run multiple instances?

Comment: multiple anonymous ip

Comment: That does not seem currently possible, because each instance of TorBrowser will try to run Tor, and if the latter is already running, you'll get an error message and the browser won't start.

Comment: What benefit do you think you'll get from running multiple instances of Tor that you wouldn't get by simply running one Tor instance (and letting Tor handle streams for you)? Tor is designed to be anonymous when used in the normal way. Multiple instances is probably not going to actually help you at all, and might even hurt your anonymity.

Answer (score 2):

I answered this [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/6904).

> This method launches multiple Tor instances, each with its own SocksPort and ControlPort. This ensures that the Tor Browsers are fully functional, portable, and self-contained. However, someone should confirm that I haven't missed anything that could compromise TBs security.
>
> 1. **Optional:** Download, verify, and install Tor Browser.
> 2. Make copies of the Tor Browser folder with different names (eg. Number them)
> 3. Launch Tor Browser
> 4. Edit about:config
>
>    - Modify extensions.torlauncher.control_port to a new ControlPort (eg. 9052 for Tor Browser 2)
> 5. Edit Torbutton Preferences
>
>    - Use custom proxy settings, and change the Port to SocksPort (eg. 9152 for Tor Browser 2)
> 6. Close Tor Browser
> 7. Edit torrc-defaults in \TorBrowser\Data\Tor
>
>    - Change SocksPort to what you set in step 5
>    - Change ControlPort to what you set in step 4
> 8. Launch Tor Browser, and check that everything was configured correctly
>
>    - Homepage (about:tor) should say "Congratulations!"
>    - Click "Test Tor Network Settings". check.torproject.org should say "Congratulations."
>    - Go to [ip-check.info](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/6904). Test should be all green and orange except Tab name. Authentication should be "protected". **Note:** It may not say that you are using Tor, but this is incorrect.
>    - **Optional:** Go to ipleak.net for IP, DNS, Geolocation, Browser and other info
>    - **Optional:** Test your browser fingerprint at [panopticlick.eff.org](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)
> 9. **Optional:** Edit about:config
>
>    - Type “banned" and modify the ports of the two entries. Add all the new SocksPort and ControlPort to the list (Copy the ports from other Tor Browsers)
> 10. **Optional:** Turn on “Forbid Scripts Globally” in NoScript for further security and privacy (also reduces browser fingerprint)
> 11. Repeat 3-10 for each Tor Browser folder
>
> Alternatively, this might be possible with a single Tor instance as the SocksPort and ControlPort. This would require the use of the control_auth_cookie (CookieAuthentication) or HashedControlPassword, and about:config extensions.torlauncher.start_tor=false. However, the browsers would not be self-contained and portable, as they would require a process that isn’t in their own directory.
>
> Inspired by mirimir's answer which seemed to compromise TB's security.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the proxy port by downloading privoxy: http://www.privoxy.org/

Set the browser proxy as following:

> ip address : 127.0.0.1
>
> port : 8118

Verify that proxy port is running. If so, you may request multiple Tor browsers.

http://www.privoxy.org/config/