# How to run multiple Tor browsers simultaneously and independently with different circuits and exit IP addresses using TBB version 4.0.3?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I have reserched a lot on the subject of how to run multiple Tor Browsers simultaneously, and independently, but could not find anything so far that make that possible.

How may I arrange the Tor Browser set-up so that I may use multiple instances of Tor Browsers running simultaneously and independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/6904).

> This method launches multiple Tor instances, each with its own SocksPort and ControlPort. This ensures that the Tor Browsers are fully functional, portable, and self-contained. However, someone should confirm that I haven't missed anything that could compromise TBs security.
>
> 1. **Optional:** Download, verify, and install Tor Browser.
> 2. Make copies of the Tor Browser folder with different names (eg. Number them)
> 3. Launch Tor Browser
> 4. Edit about:config
>
>    - Modify extensions.torlauncher.control_port to a new ControlPort (eg. 9052 for Tor Browser 2)
> 5. Edit Torbutton Preferences
>
>    - Use custom proxy settings, and change the Port to SocksPort (eg. 9152 for Tor Browser 2)
> 6. Close Tor Browser
> 7. Edit torrc-defaults in \TorBrowser\Data\Tor
>
>    - Change SocksPort to what you set in step 5
>    - Change ControlPort to what you set in step 4
> 8. Launch Tor Browser, and check that everything was configured correctly
>
>    - Homepage (about:tor) should say "Congratulations!"
>    - Click "Test Tor Network Settings". check.torproject.org should say "Congratulations."
>    - Go to [ip-check.info](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/6904). Test should be all green and orange except Tab name. Authentication should be "protected". **Note:** It may not say that you are using Tor, but this is incorrect.
>    - **Optional:** Go to ipleak.net for IP, DNS, Geolocation, Browser and other info
>    - **Optional:** Test your browser fingerprint at [panopticlick.eff.org](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)
> 9. **Optional:** Edit about:config
>
>    - Type “banned" and modify the ports of the two entries. Add all the new SocksPort and ControlPort to the list (Copy the ports from other Tor Browsers)
> 10. **Optional:** Turn on “Forbid Scripts Globally” in NoScript for further security and privacy (also reduces browser fingerprint)
> 11. Repeat 3-10 for each Tor Browser folder
>
> Alternatively, this might be possible with a single Tor instance as the SocksPort and ControlPort. This would require the use of the control_auth_cookie (CookieAuthentication) or HashedControlPassword, and about:config extensions.torlauncher.start_tor=false. However, the browsers would not be self-contained and portable, as they would require a process that isn’t in their own directory.
>
> Inspired by mirimir's answer which seemed to compromise TB's security.

Comment: Where is about:config.

Answer (score 1):

There are some answers to your question in this Q&A: [How to run multiple Tor browsers with different IPs?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips/3608#3608)

But, I have not tried them so I can not testify that these methods work. However, there is one other method suggested here:

You may setup your computer with Two or several operating systems. In each operating system you may run an independent Tor Browser. I have not tried this, but you may even be able to create different identities in given operating system, and try to run a different Tor Browser in each of these different identities.