# Mac: how to run multiple instances of Tor browser at the same time with different exit nodes?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I made two profiles of Tor Browser from the command line and I followed [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-simultaneously-and-independently-with-different) but it didn't work for Mac. I can run both Tor Browser.app and Tor Browser2.app from different ports now, but somehow I can't run them at the same time.

What I'd like to do is to run one instance of Tor Browser with the default settings, while running another with an exit node of a designated IP address. Is this possible on a Mac? If so, how? I looked into ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data but there was no separate torrc file for each of the profiles I have: there was only one that seemed to be shared across all the profiles.

Edit: although I said I followed the post I linked, there were some steps that can't be followed in my environment. These options didn't exist in my Tor browser's about:config settings.

> Modify extensions.torbutton.custom.socks_port to a new port (eg. 9152
>   for Tor Browser 2) Modify extensions.torbutton.custom.socks_host to
>   127.0.0.1 Modify extensions.torbutton.proxies_applied to false

And as for this step:

> Edit torrc-defaults in \TorBrowser\Data\Tor

I edited that torrc-defaults in /Applications/TorBrowser2.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor/torrc-defaults

And my torrc file is in ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc

My profile data is in ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/[myProfileID].[myProfileName]

And there are folders like bookmarkbackups, extensions, gmp, HTTPSEverywhereUserRules, preferences and bunch of files but not torrc here. (i.e. there are no separate torrc files for each profile, just one shared across all profiles.)

Also, in [this post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips), there's another Answer by mirmir, but a step in it can't be followed on Mac too.

> Now open the second Tor browser then TorButton Preferences. Select "Use custom settings" then change the SOCKS Port to 9152 and click OK. Browse https://check.torproject.org/ and verify that you're using Tor.

There's no TorButton Preferences in my TorBrowser.app!

Comment: There is another question regarding this topic which has a bunch of good answers. They should be easily adoptable to Mac: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/2006/88

Comment: @JensKubieziel, I followed the same answer by Tor User in the post I linked. But I can't follow some steps in it because the options mentioned in those steps didn't exist in my Tor browser's about:config. I'll update my question with those details.

Comment: @JensKubieziel, updated my question.

Comment: I updated the answers. Some settings have other names now and the `torrc` is in the subdirector `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor`. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @JensKubieziel, I already edited the torrc and torrc-defaults but the locations are different than what's described in the post (even after updates), as I wrote in my updated question. Each Tor Browser instance works fine, but it gives an error when I try to run them simultaneously. The error says "Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start."

Comment: @JensKubieziel, I already followed this but this is actually the default setting: "Modify extensions.torbutton.custom.socks_host (on newer versions this is network.proxy.socks) to 127.0.0.1" If it's the default setting, do I have to change it to something else for my second instance of Tor browser?