# Multiple instances of Tor w/ Tor Browser since v4.5

Tags: windows

I'm aware this has already been asked, but with an update to Tor browser it seems a bit more difficult to manage. See here: [How to run multiple Tor browsers with different IPs?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips)

It requires editing TorButton preferences, which is no longer an easy thing to do. How do I change my settings to use custom proxy?

I see it's possible using linux: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking

EDIT:
I found this also: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/14630

At the bottom, MikePerry says " ... you need to either edit the Torbutton about:config prefs 'extensions.torbutton.socks_host' and 'extensions.torbutton.socks_port', or set the environment variables TOR_SOCKS_HOST and TOR_SOCKS_PORT before starting TBB."

I tried doing that and it also did not work. I may have missed something very obvious though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded an older version of Tor to see what the TorButton custom proxy settings changed. I've been able to replicate that now using the latest version of TorBrowser. I've modified TorUser's answer (which was inspired by mimir's answer).

Here's how to run multiple instances of Tor Browser on Windows since the 4.5 update:

1. **Optional:** Download, verify, and install Tor Browser.
2. Make copies of the Tor Browser folder with different names (eg. Number them)
3. Launch Tor Browser
4. Edit about:config

   - Modify extensions.torlauncher.control_port to a new ControlPort (eg. 9052 for Tor Browser 2)
5. Edit TorButton Preferences (without the GUI [removed in 4.5 update])

   - Modify extensions.torbutton.custom.socks_port to a new port (eg. 9152 for Tor Browser 2)
   - Modify extensions.torbutton.custom.socks_host to 127.0.0.1
   - Modify extensions.torbutton.proxies_applied to false
   - Modify extensions.torbutton.use_privoxy to false
   - Modify network.proxy.socks_port to the same port (eg. 9152 for Tor Browser 2)
6. Close Tor Browser
7. Edit torrc-defaults in \TorBrowser\Data\Tor

   - Change SocksPort to what you set in step 5
   - Change ControlPort to what you set in step 4
8. Launch Tor Browser, and check that everything was configured correctly

   - Homepage (about:tor) should say "Congratulations!"
   - Click "Test Tor Network Settings". check.torproject.org should say "Congratulations."
   - Go to [ip-check.info](https://ip-check.info). Test should be all green and orange except Tab name. Authentication should be "protected". **Note:** It may not say that you are using Tor, but this is incorrect.
   - **Optional:** Test your browser fingerprint at [panopticlick.eff.org](https://panopticlick.eff.org)
9. **Optional:** Edit about:config

   - Type “banned" and modify the ports of the two entries. Add all the new SocksPort and ControlPort to the list (Copy the ports from other Tor Browsers)
10. **Optional:** Turn on “Forbid Scripts Globally” in NoScript for further security and privacy (also reduces browser fingerprint)
11. Repeat 3-10 for each Tor Browser folder