# How to configure multiple Tor.exes

Tags: configuration

It's very possible to have different end-nodes using the Tor Browser. see [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6846/multiple-instances-of-tor-w-tor-browser-since-v4-5)

I want to configure the .exe to do the same thing (without the TBB). [These](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) are a list of commands that help to do that (I think). Has anyone tried this before? Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provide shows how to do it.

```
tor.exe -f torrc1
tor.exe -f torrc2
tor.exe -f torrc3
```

where each of the torrc[n] files have been configured to choose different listening addresses like SOCKSPort 9999 and ORPort 5555 depending on what you're doing with these services.

to test the connections in console, run

```
tor.exe -f torrc1 | more
tor.exe -f torrc2 | more
tor.exe -f torrc3 | more
```

Each torrc needs a data directory, so I copied the directory that came with the TBB and replicated it x amount of times. Here's what the contents of my first torrc looks like:

```
DataDirectory C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor\Tor\Data directores\Data1\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor\Tor\Data directores\Data1\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor\Tor\Data directores\Data1\Tor\geoip6

SocksPort 9151
ControlPort 9051
SocksBindAddress 127.0.0.1
```

and the second:

```
DataDirectory C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor\Tor\Data directores\Data2\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor\Tor\Data directores\Data2\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor\Tor\Data directores\Data2\Tor\geoip6

SocksPort 9152
ControlPort 9052
SocksBindAddress 127.0.0.1
```