# Running multiple TOR instances in TOR browser versions 5+

Tags: configuration, windows, help, support

I have checked around but haven't found an answer to running multiple instances for V5+

Closest was for v4.5 [Multiple instances of Tor w/ Tor Browser since v4.5](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6846/multiple-instances-of-tor-w-tor-browser-since-v4-5)

Anyone have any updates for this please?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions for version 4.5? There's a further answer [here](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips?lq=1), but it's basically a duplicate of answer you've linked to.