# How to run multiple Tor browsers simultaneously on Windows?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I tried  [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips/6954#6954)  I successfully made a  copy of  the tor  folder  working  with different IPs on both tors,  but  what do I do for  the  third copy of the  tor  folder?  What  control port and  stock port should  I put on the third browser?
I need  multiple  IPs.
I made  one copy  working ( 1. the  default  tor  and  2. the  copy  folder ) 
I need to make  10-15  working copies with different IPs.

Answer (score 2):

You can just increment the Control and Socks ports by 1 for each additional instance.

So for the third browser instance, the `ControlPort` would be `9053` and the `SocksPort` would be `9153`. For the fourth instance, they would be `9054` and `9154` respectively. And so on.

Comment: on the  third  tor  it  say's  


" Could not connect to Tor control port."

Comment: Are you sure you have followed all the instructions on the thread [you referenced](http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/1730)? Can you start the third Tor instance from the command line (i.e. `cmd`) and see what logs it outputs? (i.e. `start-tor-browser -v | more`, or whatever the Windows command is.)