# Open multiple Tor browsers with different IP addresses each

Tags: ip-address

I want to launch multiple Tor browsers at the same time and each one of them having its own IP address that I set into the torcc file. I tried [this method](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips) but all secondary browsers have the same IP address of the first browser, even if I changed the `ExitNodes` in torcc file of each one.

The principle torcc file contain this code:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6


ExitNodes ip1
```

The second one contains almost the same code, except I want a different IP address:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory C:\Users\ABDEL\Desktop\tor\2\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\ABDEL\Desktop\tor\2\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\ABDEL\Desktop\tor\2\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6

ExitNodes ip2
```

Even if I connect with the second Tor, I still have this IP address ip1

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the contents of your torrc files so we can see how you're setting things up? (Just two of them should do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set different `SocksPort`s for each Tor in torrc-defaults.
Then, for each browser, you should set the socks port to match in Settings -> Advanced -> Network -> Connection Settings.

All your Tor clients are trying to open the same `SocksPort`. 9150.
The first one that starts up 'wins'. You should see in the log of the 2nd Tor that it is unable to bind the socks port.

When they each listen to their own socks port, then each browser can connect to its own Tor.

They also try to open the same `ControlPort`, but I don't know where to change that in the browser. This means that 'new circuit/identity' won't work, but in your case that matters little as you're restricted to 1 exit anyway.