# Launch multiple sessions or instances on OS X

Tags: mac

id like to have the ability to run multiple sessions in the TOR browser, on OS X.

I can't seem to install firefox extensions that fix multiple sessions, since they are not compatible it seems.

I can't copy the application and rename it, this causes a crash when i attempt to start the second instance of the browser, even if i change ports etc in torrc.

I can't launch multiple instances via shell with

```
/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -f /usr/local/etc/torrc
```

"A copy of Tor Browser is already open. Only one copy of Tor Browser can be open at a time."

So, how do i do this?

Comment: If you haven't found it already, have a look at https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips

Answer (score 1):

Tor browser is still a firefox, so take a look at the [official manual here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)
The sequence is :

1. Create a profile in Profile Manager
2. Launch a different instance specifying your new(alternate) profile for each separate session

If you need a separate instances of Tor too, take a look at `DataDirectory DIR` in your torrc, make a copy of your `torrc` but change a directory path. That's it =) Feel free to ask further questions!

Comment: This creates two different profiles on your local machine, but when you visit the same website with both instances (say, you want to appear as two different persons in a chat), still both instances use the same circuit and therefore, using these two instances, both instances come from the same exit node, and so the target web-server will see the same IP-addresses from both instances. So, the target still knows that your two instances belong to the same physical person.