# How to run multiple Tor browsers with different IPs on the latest version 6.5.1?

Tags: torsocks

I would like to run multiple Tor Browsers on Windows all at once, with each having a unique Tor IP address.

I have already seen [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips) instruction, but it doesn't work anymore as extensions.torbutton.custom.socks_port and extensions.torbutton.custom.socks_host were removed from the latest version. Please post simple instructions, as I'm new to this and would appreciate help.

Comment: In the instruction you linked are the updated config values in brackets behind the outdated ones.