# tor for windows command line problem

Tags: windows

I have a problem specifying command line options to tor. trying to execute like this:

C:\path-to-tor\firefox.exe -help
doesn't produce anything

Just C:...\firefox.exe http://someurl.com
works and opens the URL so it accepts something (url) but anything else (I wanted to set up custom torrc but it seems -f also doesn't work

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: firefox is just firefox, if you want a custom torrc you need to edit `C:\path-to-tor\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc`

Comment: Thanks but my idea is to be able to run tor with several different predefined rc files. Changing the default torrc works OK. The problem I am describing is that when I specify my own torrc using -f as per documentation it doesn't read it. Actually it doesn't seem any of the parameters to work even --help...

Comment: Right, you won't be able to do that. Tor Browser's Tor Launcher addon will launch a copy of Tor referencing the torrc file. Command line inputs passed to firefox won't affect how Tor Launcher runs Tor. You could look at [this Q/A](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips) for how to run multiple instances of Tor Browser, each with it's own config.

Comment: This other thread is about how to launch multiple instances. I still don't get why command line options don't work. I need just one instance but to set a custom torrc file. As per tor's manual https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en this could be done with -n option: -f FILE == Specify a new configuration file to contain further Tor configuration options. But this doesn't work so I am curious should I set something else or not. Aren't these command line options that can be passed while starting tor? And as I said -help should show some help, but it doesn't...

Comment: `firefox.exe` isn't `tor.exe` so those command line options don't apply.