# Does running multiple Tor instances with multiple exit nodes this way really compromise Tor security?

Tags: security

I have followed steps in [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips) article and could successfully run two tor instances with different exit nodes (IPs duplicate if more than 2 nodes are used) and checked Tor status using following sites and all reported success:
check.torproject.org 
ip-check.info
panopticlick.eff.org

BUT some say in the article this way compromise  Tor security , How do i make sure that i'm not messing anything up ?

Comment: Potentially, yes. For example mirimir's answer fails to update the banned ports lists, opening up the control port and the socks port to potential cross-protocol attacks. There may be other resulting issues too from unexpected interactions like that, which is why it's not officially supported.

Comment: @canonizingironize Does TorUser's answer also compromise Tor's security ?. If yes , What should i do to be able to run multiple Tor browsers on the same machine (without Virtual Machine). ?

Comment: It may, it's not supported. I don't see anything obvious but it's certainly possible that it does in some way I can't anticipate.