# How to update Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu, update

Following the instructions at [How to run multiple Tor browsers with different IPs?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips) I now have multiple folders that can host a different Tor Browser instance.

How can I update all of them on Ubuntu without downloading ~50 MB for each one?
(by updating via "Help" --> "About Tor Browser")

(I would like to keep the *unique* bookmarks and settings for each one. Therefore, I cannot simply copy the steps I took in the above link)

Answer (score 2):

You could export settings and bookmarks by copying the files from somewhere in

> Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default

Answer (score 1):

Download the [`.mar` file](https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/) and learn to use `mar-tools` to [manually apply the update](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Manually_Installing_a_MAR_file) for each copy of your browser.