# How to use multiple profiles with Tor?

Tags: configuration, firefox, ubuntu, terminal

Firefox allows for the ability to use multiple profiles by starting the browser from the command line as such:
`firefox --ProfileManager`
Or more directly:
`firefox --CreateProfile`

However, despite being included in `tor --help` , these commands do not work when I replace `firefox` with `tor`. The browser starts normally without any other options.

Is there a workaround to navigate this important Firefox functionality to the Tor Browser? I'm running Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if they appeared on `tor --help` since `tor` isn't at all related to `firefox`.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work, given that Tor Browser ships with a specific default profile which it uses, and needs to use to operate properly, creating and utilising different profiles will cause issues.

Instead, have multiple installations of Tor Browser (each extracted to a distinct folder) which will provide superior isolation between identities and profiles for each.

Comment: Will I be able to run these simultaneously? That is a condition.

Comment: Not easily, no, but neither would using different profiles.

Comment: I am looking to do this, even if it is difficult. Can you direct me to something that addresses this?

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips