# How to run multiple Tor browsers with different IPs on version 9?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows, support

I've read [This Instruction](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips?newreg=8cc598ec35a04af0acba85330019e30f) but it's outdated and I couldn't comment on it because of reputation.
I would like to run multiple Tor Browsers all at once, with each having a unique Tor IP address.
And I'm using Windows . [ it's better to explain in different OS ] 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Tor itself doesn't recommend running multiple browsers: https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-36/
Did you try to follow this answer: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6401/88
If so, what went wrong?

Comment: I saw that and I did the same but step 7 is not possible in the latest version and I don't know what to do about it @JensKubieziel